# RegEx for number not in a certain range

Tags: regex

I am struggling to make a RegExp to parse a string to determine if the number is in a certain range.

So what I am trying to achieve is:

- 1     - 32499 (Valid)
- 32500 - 32532 (Not Valid)
- 32533 - 65534 (Valid)
- 65535 - infinity (Not Valid)

From reading I will also have to make a special case for 1digit numbers?

I am using this to try and test:

[Online regEx Tester](http://regex101.com/)

Comment: i think it would be better to use math comparision of the language of your choice. On the other hand it looks like you want to check for bit range and only disallow small range inbetween 0-65635. So min/max shouldn't be a problem to find. Only the 33 positions in the middle are bit tricky, but not really.

Comment: what about `number > range1 && number < range2` and add more condition

Comment: I can do this with maths option, however its for a model validation attribute and asp.net has a built in RegEx attribute. So Im trying the more elegant approach, if I cant get it right I will go with the math approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Better way is to check conditionally in the code. If not possible then use regex at last resort

```
(?!325([0-2][0-9]|3[0-2])|65535)^[1-5][0-9]{0,4}|6[0-4][0-9]{3}|65[0-4][0-9]{2}|655[0-2][0-9]|6553[0-4]$
```

[Online demo](http://regex101.com/r/mI0gQ0/1)

Read more about [Negative Lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

---

Pattern explanation:

```
(?!325([0-2][0-9]|3[0-2])|65535)
```

is used to exclude certain number from the match.

`^` and `$` is used to match whole string/line from beginning to end.

Comment: You champion! And +1 for the extra info and explanation!